# Is this proof of $C[0,1]$ and $C[a,b]$ being isometric correct?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, solution-verification

From the book *Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications-Kreyszig*:

> Let $C[a,b]$ be the metric space of continuous, real valued functions defined on $[a,b]\subset \mathbb{R}$ with the metric $d(x,y)=\max_{t\in[a,b]}|x(t)-y(t)|$. Show that for any choice of $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ with $a<b$, $C[0,1]$ and $C[a,b]$ are isometric.

By definition, two metric spaces are isometric if there exists an *bijective isometry* between the spaces, in other words a bijective mapping $T:X\to Y$ such that for all $x,y\in X$: $d_{X}(x,y)=d_{Y}(Tx,Ty)$.

**My attempt:** Between $[0,1],[a,b]\subset \mathbb{R}$ there exists an bijective mapping $f:[b,a]\to[0,1]$ defined by $f(x)=\frac{x-a}{b-a}$ whos inverse is $f^{-1}(x)=x(b-a)+a$. We define $T:C[0,1]\to C[a,b]$ by $Tx(t)=x(f(t))$. I claim that $T$ is a bijective isometry:

*Injective*: Suppose that $Tx=Ty$ then by the coincidence axiom $$d(Tx,Ty)=\max_{t\in [a,b]}|x(f(t))-y(f(t))|=0.$$ since $f$ is a bijection this implies that $$\max_{t\in[0,1]}|x(t)-y(t)|=0$$
that is $x=y$ and $T$ is thus injective.

*Surjective*: Assume that $y\in C[a,b]$ then $y(f^{-1}(t))\in C[0,1]$ and $T(y(f^{-1}(t)))=y(t)$ so $T$ is surjective and hence bijective.

*Distance preserving*: Let us suppose that $x,y \in C[0,1]$ and the maximum between $x$ and $y$ occurs at $t_{0}\in[0,1]$ then $f^{-1}(t_{0})=t_{0}(b-a)+a\in [a,b]$ and since for every $t\in [a,b]: f(t)\in[0,1]$
$$d(Tx,Ty)=\max_{t\in[a,b]}|x(f(t))-y(f(t))|=|x(f(f^{-1}(t_{0})))-y(f(f^{-1}(t_{0})))|=d(x,y)$$

Therefore we conclude that $T$ is an isometry between $C[0,1]$ and $C[a,b]$ and thus they are isometric spaces.

> Question: is this correct?

PS. Any comments would also be helpful!

Comment: You never used (or even stated) the continuity of $f$. But without that, how do you know that $x \circ f$ is continuous if $x$ is? [You don't, if $f$ isn't continuous then there typically are (and in this example there definitely are) continuous $x$ such that $x\circ f$ is discontinuous.] And for the surjectivity you need the continuity of $f^{-1}$. More generally, if $X,Y$ are compact and $f \colon X \to Y$ is a homeomorphism, then $y \mapsto y \circ f$ is an isometric isomorphism $C(Y) \to C(X)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Good point! I had assumed it to be the case but failed to state it, thanks for pointing it out! I will expand my own notes to fix these issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. Note also that $T$ is a linear map, so we can really identify $C([a,b])$ with $C([0,1]$) as Banach spaces! One says that $C([a,b])$ and $C([0,1])$ are isometrically isomorphic Banach spaces.